# Automatically stringifying object when inserting to a MySQL JSON column with knex

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, typescript, knex.js

Let's jump straight to an example code:

```
create table test_json_table
(
    data json not null
);
```

I can insert to the table like this:

```
const columns = { data: "{ some_json: 123 }" }; // notice that the data column is passed as string
await knex('test_json_table').insert(columns);
```

And get data from the table like this:

```
await knex('test_json_table').select();
// returns:
// [ 
//   { data: { some_json: 123 } } // notice that the data is returned as parsed JavaScript object (not a string)
// ]
```

When inserting a row the JSON column needs to be passed as a serialised string. When retrieving the row, an already parsed object is returned.

This is creating quite a mess in the project. We are using TypeScript and would like to have the same type for inserts as for selects, but this makes it impossible. It'd be fine to either always have string or always object.

I found this topic being discussed at other places, so it looks like I am not alone in this ([link](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1800), [link](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1727)). It seems like there is no way to convert the object to string automatically. Or I am missing something?

It'd be nice if knex provided a hook where we could manually serialise the object into string when inserting.

What would be the easiest way to achieve that? Is there any **lightweight** ORM with support for that? Or any other option?

Answer (score 2):

You could try `objection.js` that allows you to declare certain columns to be marked as json attributes and those should be stringified automatically when inserting / updating their values https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/model/static-properties.html#static-jsonattributes

I haven't tried if it works with mysql though. I don't see any reason why it wouldn't.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to avoid adding an ORM, but it looks like it will not be possible to do without it :(

Comment: Objection is really lightweight and is not trying to hide the fact that you are actually using SQL database under the hood. It will not prevent you from writing any kind of SQL that you would do with knex. It is basically just set of hooks and declarations to make handling relations easier than manually written joins.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way using jsonb data type. [mysql json type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)

We prefer postgresql for this kind of problem at office, easier and solid database for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but switching to a different database is not an option for us.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could call your own function before inserting that converts all objects to string and call it every time before you insert.

You can probably wrap knex to do it automatically as well.