# Knex.js multiple hasTables seems to create pushed array

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I've noticed an odd behaviour in Knex which might be intentional, but if so I'd like to know how to avoid this.

When running multiple `hasTable()` queries in a row, it appears to "cache" the previous queries and chain them all together into an array.

```
async setup() {
  const { schema } = this.db.knex;
  const hasPhotos = await schema.hasTable('photos');
  const hasAnswers = await schema.hasTable('answers');
  const hasOther = await schema.hasTable('other');
  console.log(hasPhotos);
  console.log(hasAnswers);
  console.log(hasOther);
}
```

Expected output:

```
true
false
false
```

Actual output:

```
true
[ true, false ]
[ true, false, false ]
```

Any idea why this is? If I use the `.then()` syntax rather than a/a I get the same results.

Comment: I should also add that if you do it completely by the book, as per their docs, it will still do it as an array if there's more than one check, which seems really odd to me

Comment: I also found such odd type of behavior of `knex.js` before days, see this...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532384/automatically-stringifying-object-when-inserting-to-a-mysql-json-column-with-kne/57656590#57656590

Comment: Seems to be saving the value into the `schema` object. This looks like a bug to me. You should report it: https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues. If you include a reproducible test case it will help the maintainers review it.

Comment: Schema builder does append all calls made to it to the same builder... maybe it should clear old queries when builder is executed. Definitely good thing to discuss in knex github issues.

Comment: I created a GH issue: https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/3421 perhaps further discussion in there can be brought back into SO.